# COBOL's EVALUATE: How to have an empty WHEN OTHER clause?

Tags: cobol

```
EVALUATE MyValue
WHEN 1
    DISPLAY "My value is 1"
WHEN 2
    DISPLAY "My value is 2"
WHEN OTHER
* Actually I don't need to do anything
END-EVALUATE
```

I think to have read somewhere that a COBOL application will crash for an `EVALUATE` where the `WHEN` clauses do not cover the value of the evaluated variable, if there is no `WHEN OTHER` statement present. So, in order to avoid the crash, I wanted to add this empty `WHEN OTHER`. 
Under which circumstances is this necessary, and if so, is this approach correct?

Comment: According to the documentation we both read, the WHEN OTHER is optional.  If you want to code the WHEN OTHER clause, CONTINUE might work as a placeholder.

Comment: It's not *required* but it's good practice to code WHEN OTHER on an EVALUATE.  It lets the reader of your code know which conditions you explicitly choose to handle or ignore  rather than just the one's you remembered to.

Comment: @JimCastro let's say "it is good practice for some and bad practice for others - do whatever you teams' rule is, if there isn't one: do what the program you adjust does to stay concise; if it is new one: make up your mind".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Under which circumstances is this necessary

It is definitely necessary if the compiler ist configured to abort if the `when other` statement ist missing. ;-)

Otherwise, in my opinion it is good practice to programm an `when other` statement even if it only takes a `continue`.

Comment: Thank you, I needed this doubt confirmed

Comment: Can you elaborate on any compiler (configuration) that actually can be configured that the `WHEN OTHER` clause needs to be coded?

Answer (score 9):

> Under which circumstances is this necessary ...

Under no circumstances with every COBOL environment I know of (*might* be "some"); and isn't necessary for any COBOL 85/2002/2014/future compiler.

> ... and if so, is this approach correct?

No, actually COBOL 85/2002/2014/future-compliant compiler will raise an error because of a missing imperative statement (there are some compilers allowing this as "extension" [I'd say it is a bug], some at least warn, some stay silent).
If there are some "really strange reasons" to always include the `WHEN OTHER`: use the (nearly no-op) statement `CONTINUE` as "statement".

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
EVALUATE MyValue
WHEN 1
    DISPLAY "My value is 1"
WHEN 2
    DISPLAY "My value is 2"
WHEN OTHER
    CONTINUE
END-EVALUATE.
```